# Acceder a método de otro objeto

Tags: javascript

En el siguiente código creo un objeto oferta en que ejemplo_lavadora es un objeto Lavadora:
`let oferta_lavadora = new Oferta(ejemplo_lavadora, 629, 40, 15);`

Necesito dentro de la clase oferta acceder y mostrar el método del objeto Lavadora (en este caso) resum() que devuelve información del objeto pasado como primer parámetro:

````
    constructor(marca, model, ample, alt, fons, pes, capacitat_kg, revolucions, estoc){
        super("Rentadora", marca, model, ample, alt, fons, pes, estoc);
        this.capacitat_kg=capacitat_kg;
        this.revolucions=revolucions;
      
        
    }

    resum(){
        
        return "Tipus: "+this.tipus+" Marca: "+this.marca+" Model: "+this.model+" Ample: "+this.ample+" Alt: "+this.alt+" Fons: "+this.fons+" Pes: "+this.pes+" Capacitat:"+this.capacitat_kg+" Revolucions: "+this.revolucions+" Estoc:"+this.estoc;
    }```

---

Perdón por no explicarme bien. Tengo una superclase Electrodoméstico y tres subclases (Lavadora, Frigorífico y Lavavajillas). Cada subclase tiene un método resum() que devuelve las propiedades con sus valores después de crear un objeto.
Luego tengo la clase oferta que dependiendo qué objeto recibe como primer parámetro en su constructor, accederá a un resum() u otro. En este caso recibe un objeto Lavadora y quiero que en el resum() de la clase Oferta, se acceda al resum() de la clase Lavadora.
let oferta_rentadora = new Oferta(ejemplo_lavadora, 629, 40, 15);
````

class Oferta{
constructor(electrodomestic, preu, preu_transport, descompte){
this.electrodomestic=electrodomestic;
this.preu=preu;
this.preu_transport=preu_transport;
this.descompte=descompte;
}

```
resum(){
   return ;
}
```

}

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Dónde ocurre el error en concreto y qué error es?

Answer (score 1):

En el metodo resum() de la clase Oferta debes devolver lo que otorga el metodo resum() de la clase Lavadora (que es una hija de la clase Electrodomestico). Si lo que entendí es correcto, no deberias hacer eso justamente, cual sería el impedimento?.

```
class Oferta{
    constructor(electrodomestic, preu, preu_transport, descompte){
        this.electrodomestic=electrodomestic;
        this.preu=preu;
        this.preu_transport=preu_transport;
        this.descompte=descompte;  
    }



    resum(){
        return this.electrodomestic.resum();/*Tu electrodomestico esta guardado
                                             aca segun el constructor, tal vez
                                             deberias hacerlo mas explicito con 
                                             un atributo de clase.*/
    }
}
```

Espero que sea de ayuda.